# Read authors from file

Tags: external-files, input

At our university, we students write a lot of summaries in LaTeX. We have the convention of adding a CONTRIBUTORS.txt file to the repository containing the document code, which lists all contributors line by line.

A file could look like this:

```
John Doe (jdoe)
Jane Roe (jroe)
```

I'd like to use those names in the `\authors` declaration.

The lines in the textfile (delimited by newlines) should be shown in the document separated with commas or newlines.

The current code I'm using:

```
\author{\InputIfFileExists{CONTRIBUTORS.txt}{\relax}{https://github.com/HSR-Stud/}}
```

...ignores newline characters, as LaTeX requires either `\\` or an empty line to insert an actual newline in the generated document.

How can I insert all the names from the CONTRIBUTORS.txt file as comma or newline separated values?

Bonus question: How can I cut off the part inside the braces, so that the example file above would result in `John Doe, Jane Roe`?

---

Edit: The solution should also work if a person has two or more names (like "Gian Marco De Luca").

Comment: This would be very easy if your work flow allows you to process `CONTRIBUTORS.txt` with a script (in `python` or `awk` or ...) before inclusion in your `LaTeX` document. Since a `makefile` answers another of your questions here that's likely. Others on this site may provide a `TeX` only solution.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks, that's a very good point that I totally forgot about :) Still, if there is a native TeX solution that would be nice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a version with LaTeX3 macros:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\authorsfromfile} { O{,~} m }
 {
  \IfFileExists{#2}
   { \bargen_authors:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
   { \author{\texttt{https://github.com/HSR-Stud/}} }
 }
\ior_new:N \l_bargen_file_ior
\seq_new:N \bargen_authors_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \bargen_authors:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_bargen_authors_seq
  \ior_open:Nn \l_bargen_file_ior { #2 }
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \l_bargen_file_ior 
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l_bargen_authors_seq { \tl_trim_spaces:n { ##1 } }
   }
  \author { \seq_use:Nnnn \l_bargen_authors_seq { #1 } { #1 } { #1 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\authorsfromfile{CONTRIBUTORS.txt}
\title{Document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

You can also do

```
\authorsfromfile[\and]{CONTRIBUTORS.txt}
```

that would use the traditional `\and` separator between authors.

Basically we read the file line by line and deliver the sequence thus obtained to the `\author` macro, with items separated by the optional argument to `\authorsfromfile` (default is "comma and space").

The advantage of this approach is that the line

```
\seq_put_right:Nx \l_bargen_authors_seq { \tl_trim_spaces:n { ##1 } }
```

can be modified in various ways, for example to process the input line for changing the appearance of the nickname.

---

A "classical" implementation, where we use the `catchfile` package to read the file; each line is delimited by `^^J`, a character that won't appear in any reasonable text file. Also the nickname will be stripped off; the names are inserted in a `\mbox` in order not to split them across lines in the title page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\authorsfromfile}[2][, ]{%
  \IfFileExists{#2}
    {\CatchFileDef\authors@list{#2}{\endlinechar=`^^J }\authors@do{#1}}
    {\author{\texttt{https://github.com/HSR-Stud/}}}%
}
\def\authors@final@list{}
\def\authors@do#1{%
  \def\authors@sep{#1}%
  \expandafter\authors@do@aux\authors@list\@nil
}
\def\authors@do@aux#1^^J#2\@nil{%
  \authors@strip@parens{#1}%
  \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\authors@final@list\expandafter{\authors@current}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
    \author{\authors@final@list}%
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\authors@final@list\expandafter{\authors@sep}%
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {\authors@do@aux#2\@nil}%
}
\def\authors@strip@parens#1{\authors@strip@aux#1 (\@nil}
\def\authors@strip@aux#1 (#2\@nil{\def\authors@current{\mbox{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\authorsfromfile{CONTRIBUTORS.txt}
\title{Document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Again, one can also call this as

```
\authorsfromfile[\and]{CONTRIBUTORS.txt}
```

to get the standard separation between different authors. If the file is missing, a standard "author" will appear.

As it is it won't work if the file exists but is empty; one might add a check for it.

In order to make a long list of authors be well typeset by the `article` class you need to change `\maketitle` or, more precisely, `\@maketitle`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    \begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
    \large\centering\@author
    \end{minipage}
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother
```

Here's what's printed if the file contains

```
John Doe (jdoe)
Jane Roe (jroe)
Christian Fässler
Jonas Furrer
Danilo Bargen
```

[image]

Comment: This looks nice, but the requirement of LaTeX3 is a disadvantage, as many people still use Texlive2009 (which afaik doesn't ship LaTeX packages).

Comment: @DaniloBargen Happily also Debian based distributions have TeX Live 2012, now.

Comment: @DaniloBargen I've added a "classical" implementation

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I'll accept your answer :) Two details I noted: It doesn't cut off the part inside the parentheses (but that wasn't strictly required) and if the author list is too long, it gets cut off. I worked around that by using \\ as a separator, but a generic approach that would work with commas too would be nicer. Also, I think it would probably be cleaner to simply "return" the text to be used inside \author, so that the user could still process it, don't you think?

Comment: @DaniloBargen You should redefine `\maketitle` for that. I'll add both the nickname stripping and a suggestion on how to modify `\maketitle` for the `article` class.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks! :) By the way, an easier solution than overwriting maketitle would be `\author{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering\authors@final@list}}%`, right? Bonus is, this works with scrartcl too. The adjusted version (which also supports fallback value as a 2nd argument) is here: https://github.com/dbrgn/texutils/blob/master/authorsfromfile.tex

Comment: @DaniloBargen Just copy the definition of `\@maketitle` from `scrartcl.cls` and do the same changes; those parts are very similar and it shouldn't be hard to see what to do.

Comment: Parbox had some problems with alignment, the varwidth package and `\author{\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}\centering\authors@final@list\end{varwidth}}` worked perfectly though.

Answer (score 7):

One way would be to use [the `datatool` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatool):

[image]

### Notes:

- The usual separators is a comma, but we can redefine that to be a space using `\DTLsetseparator{ }`.
- `\DTLiffirstrow` is used to ensure that we don't add a comma separators in the output until after the first row has been printed.
- To handle the case of middle names we make use of `\DTLifnull` to test if the 3 or 4 fields were provided.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}

\usepackage{filecontents}% Comment to prevent overwriting CONTRIBUTORS.txt
\begin{filecontents*}{CONTRIBUTORS.txt}
John Doe (jdoe) 
Jane Roe (jroe)
John Michael Doe (jmdoe)
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}


\DTLsetseparator{ }
\DTLloadrawdb[
    noheader,
    keys={
        FirstName,%
        MiddleOrLastName,%
        LastNameOrUserId,%
        UserIdWithMiddleName%
    }]{MyDB}{CONTRIBUTORS.txt}

\textbf{Contributors:}
%\DTLdisplaydb{MyDB}\par% useful for debugging
\DTLforeach{MyDB}{
    \FirsName=FirstName,%
    \MiddleOrLastName=MiddleOrLastName,%
    \LastNameOrUserId=LastNameOrUserId,%
    \UserIdWithMiddleName=UserIdWithMiddleName%
}{%
    \DTLiffirstrow{ }{, }% add comma separator AFTER first entry
    \DTLifnull{\UserIdWithMiddleName}{%
        \FirsName{} \MiddleOrLastName
    }{%
        \FirsName{} \MiddleOrLastName{} \LastNameOrUserId
    }%
}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this looks interesting. I guess this wouldn't work if the contributors have middle names (like `John Michael Doe (jmdoe)`, right? Would there be a fix for that? (Sorry for not clarifying that from the beginning...)

Comment: @DaniloBargen: Have updated solution to allow for optional middle names.

Answer (score 5):

For reference, here would be a Makefile/awk/sed solution as proposed by @ethan-bolker:

```
contributors.tex:
    echo "% Autogenerated, do not edit" > contributors.tex
    echo "\\newcommand{\\contributors}{`awk '{split($$0, a, \"(\"); gsub(/[ \t]+$$/, \"\", a[1]); printf(\"%s, \", a[1])}' CONTRIBUTORS.txt | sed 's/, $$//'`}" >> contributors.tex
```

It can be used by including `contributors.tex`:

```
\input{contributors.tex}
\author{\contributors}
```

Which results in...

[image: Screenshot]