# Fallback text in header if overlapping occurs

Tags: header-footer, positioning

I'm currently working on several projects, where the [authors are read from a textfile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91529/read-authors-from-file/91573). I'm also displaying the authors in the header using fancyhdr. This works great if there are just 2 or 3 contributors, but if there are more, the text starts overlapping.

[image: screenshot]

The overlapping is also dependent on the document title, which is shown the left.

**Is there a way to detect whether the text overlaps, and if it does, use a fallback text (an URL) instead of the authors instead?**

Header specification looks like this at the moment:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Fancy headers

% Capture title and author
\makeatletter                                                                                                                                         
\let\Title\@title
\let\Author\@author
\makeatother

% Fancy headers configuration
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % Clear all header fields
\fancyhead[LO,LE]{\bfseries \Title}
\fancyhead[RO,RE]{\Author}
\fancyfoot{} % Clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{Page \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say

```
\makeatletter
\let\Title\@title
\let\Author\@author
\normalfont\sbox0{\normalfont\Title\quad\Author}
\ifdim\wd0>\textwidth\def\Author{<whatever>}\fi
```

This will use `<whatever>` if there's not at least a quad of space between the title and the list of authors.